How do I get the ticker/stock symbols for the Kraken API?
How do I get all the ticker/stock symbols for the Kraken API so that I can run this python script on different stock symbols?
https://support.kraken.com/hc/en-us/articles/360029077772-Python-code-to-retrieve-historical-time-and-sales-trading-history-
I am not sure how to get a list of all the symbols.
The example code shows XXBTZUSD as the ticker/stock symbol.
How do I find the other ticker/stock symbols for the API?

Documentation for Get Ticker Information says the parameter pair is optional and the default is "all tradable exchange pairs".
So this should give you the full list:
import requests
import json
url = "https://api.kraken.com/0/public/Ticker"
headers = { 'Accept': 'application/json' }
response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data={})
result = json.loads(response.text)["result"]
for pair in result:
  print(pair)

Fiddle
Output looks like:

AMPUSD ANKREUR ANKRUSD ANKRXBT ANTETH ANTEUR ANTUSD ANTXBT APEEUR
APEUSD APEUSDT API3EUR API3USD APTEUR APTUSD ARBEUR ARBUSD ARKMEUR
ARKMUSD ARPAEUR ARPAUSD ASTREUR ASTRUSD ATLASEUR ATLASUSD ATOMETH
ATOMEUR ATOMGBP ATOMUSD ATOMUSDT ATOMXBT AUCTIONEUR AUCTIONUSD
AUDIOEUR AUDIOUSD AUDJPY AUDUSD AURYEUR AURYUSD AVAXEUR AVAXUSD
AVAXUSDT AXLEUR AXLUSD AXSEUR AXSUSD BADGEREUR BADGERUSD BALEUR BALUSD
BALXBT BANDEUR BANDUSD BATETH BATEUR BATUSD BATXBT BCHAUD BCHCHF.....

